# Connecting two routers via serial

Tags: router, connection, serial

I'm new to Cisco and I wanted to connect two routers with serial connection. This is how my network looks now:

[image: Network]

Maybe I connected them wrong because when I try to ping from PC0 to either PC2 or PC3 I get destination host unreachable on the IP of Router0. So I had an idea that there aren't routes between my FastEthernet and Serial ports and I tried to do that but I'm not sure how or if that's even the right approach.

As I said I'm new to this and my knowledge is not large but please if you have any directions, I'd very much appreciate it! Also I'm sorry if I used any wrong terminology since that's also new to me!

EDIT: I forgot, here is some more info on my devices in question:
Router0 has an IP of 192.168.0.1 for Fe0/0 and 192.168.1.1 for Fe0/1 and for Serial 0/1/0 it has an IP of 10.10.10.1. All of them have subnet of 255.255.255.0

Router1 has an IP of 192.168.2.1 for Fe0/0 and 192.168.3.1 for Fe0/1 and also for Serial 0/1/0 it has an IP of 10.10.10.2. Also 255.255.255.0 subnet mask.

My ultimate goal is to be able to ping from PC0 (192.168.0.10) or PC1 (192.168.1.10) to PC2 (192.168.2.10) or PC3 (192.168.3.10) and vice versa!

Comment: Can the two routers ping each other through the serial connection?

Comment: @kasperd Yes they can! both of them return the following:
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 2/9/15 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just be missing routing table entries.

- On Router0 you need to specify a route to 192.168.2.0/23 using 10.10.10.2 as gateway.
- On Router1 you need to specify a route to 192.168.0.0/23 using 10.10.10.1 as gateway.

Comment: Sorry, It didn't accept my command the first time. Now it works but I still don't understand why use these IP addresses. If it's not a bother could you explain that to me or link somewhere to read about it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually I think I got it! Thank you very very much! This community on Serverfault never lets me down :)

Comment: If you need to know more about the notation, the Wikipedia article on CIDR may be a good starting point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR

Comment: I did understand that part (I even printed out a nice sheet with all of it for now until I hopefully memorize most of it) but I was confused why did you use this specific IPs but I think I understand!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all routes are configured on each device in their areas. Set up OSPF routes and make sure both routers have them. And make sure both routers can ping each other as well. Routing tables in both routers have to reflect the other network for this to work add a default route.